# How to get attribute name of a descriptor from within __get__?

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-descriptors

When implementing a descriptor, it is possible to use `__set_name__` to register under which attribute name the descriptor was set.

Although, suppose we were to set more than one attribute to the same descriptor, then there seems to be no way to know through which name the descriptor was accessed in the `__get__` and `__set__` method.

### Code

```
class Prop:
    def  __init__(self):
        self._names = {}

    def __set_name__(self, owner, name):
        print(f'Attribute \'{name}\' was set to a Prop')

        if owner in self._names:
            self._names[owner].append(name)
        else:
            self._names[owner] = [name]

    def __get__(self, instance, owner):
        print(f'Prop was accessed through one of those: {self._names[owner]}')

prop = Prop()

class Foo:
    bar = prop
    baz = prop

foo = Foo()
foo.baz
```

### Output

```
Attribute 'bar' was set to a Prop
Attribute 'baz' was set to a Prop
Prop was accessed through one of those: ['bar', 'baz']
```

Is there a clean and general way to know from which attribute a descriptor was accessed?

Comment: Why would you use the same descriptor instance multiple times? I am just asking because that sounds like an xy Problem.

Comment: Yes, you should be using separate instances of the class. If you really need the descriptor to know its attribute name (it smells bad), pass that in when you instantiate.

Comment: This is no an XY problem. There is not specific example behind that other than the thought that the use cases of `__set_name__` seem pretty limited. This led me to think that if the attribute name was obtainable on set, it could be on get.

Comment: Not sure if the discussion in PEP-487 explaining why `__set_name__` was added is what you are looking for.

Comment: @chepner Yes thanks that is helpful, I see that it was suggested it was called `__set_owner__` instead of `__set_name__` which would have seemed more appropriate since it is the owner that matters.

Comment: Also, one use case of using the same descriptor instance across multiple objects would be to have a shared attribute.

Comment: It's relatively okay to use the same descriptor across multiple classes (though still not recommended), but not for two different attributes on the same object.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Is there a clean and general way to know from which attribute a descriptor was accessed?

No, there is no clean and general way.

However if you want a dirty hack (please don't do that!) you can avoid the descriptor protocol and just pass in the name through which it was accessed manually:

```
class Descriptor:
    def __get__(self, instance, owner, name=None):
        print(f"Property was accessed through {name}")
        return 'foo'

p = Descriptor()

class Test:
    a = p
    b = p

    def __getattribute__(self, name):
        for klass in type(self).__mro__:
            if name in klass.__dict__ and isinstance(klass.__dict__[name], Descriptor):
                return klass.__dict__[name].__get__(self, klass, name)
        else:
            return object.__getattribute__(self, name)
```